# invalid Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters (43:13)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

hello im a noob in react and am trying to pass the car.id using props to my editcar component  so i can update it via firebase , however im getting a an error Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters (43:13) any idea how i can pass the car.id to edit function? thanks for the help!

> admin_cars.js

```
<ul className="TaskList">
  {
    Cars.map(car => (
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{car.id}</th>
        <td>{car.year}</td>
        <td>{car.make}</td>
        <td>{car.model}</td>
        <td>{car.body_type}</td>
        <td>{car.int_color}</td>
        <td><img src={car.link} height="92" /> </td>
        <td>{car.price}</td> 
        <td>{car.status ? "Available" : "Sold"}</td>
        <td>
          <Link to={`/admin/editcar/${this.props.car.id}`}>
            <Icon icon={pencil} />
          </Link>
        </td>

      </tr>
    ))
  }
</ul>
```

> edit_car.js

```
 import { CarsRef, timeRef } from './reference';
    class EditCar extends Component {
        state = {
        year: '',
        make: '',
        model: '',
        trim: '',
        engine: '',
        drive_type: '',
        body_type: '',
        ext_color: '',
        int_color: '',
        transmission: '',
        price: 0,
        sale: 0,
        status: true,
        vin: '',
        link: '',
        elect_stab: '',
        wireless: '',
        seat: '',
        keyless: '',
        trip_comp: '',
        tire_pressure: '',
        wiper: '',
        id:'',
        headlight: '',
        alertMsg: false
      }

    editcar = (e, car.id) => {
      alert(this.car.id)
        e.preventDefault();

      const NewCar= {
          body_type: this.state.body_type.trim(),
          wiper: this.state.wiper,
          headlight: this.state.headlight,
          make: this.state.make,
          link: this.state.link,
          engine: this.state.engine,
          transmission:this.state.transmission,
          vin:this.state.vin,
          seat: this.state.seat, 
          price: this.state.price,
          ext_color: this.state.ext_color,
          checked: false,
          starred: false,
          timestamp: timeRef
        };

        CarsRef.child().update(NewCar);

        this.setState({ body_type: '' });
        this.setState({ wiper: '' });
        this.setState({ make: '' });
        this.setState({link:''});
        this.setState({ headlight: '' });
        this.setState({price: ''});
        this.setState({transmission: ''});
        this.setState({engine: ''});
        this.setState({vin: ''});
        this.setState({ext_color: ''});
        this.setState({id: ''})
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be related to your `editcar` method. The second parameter is not valid and you probably meant for it to be `car` and not `car.id`, so:

change

```
editcar = (e, car.id) => {}
```

to

```
editcar = (e, car) => {}
```